# Периодически простые запросы уходят в mysql slow query

Tags: mysql, pdo

При мониторинге медленных запросов периодически (каждые 20-30 минут) простые запросы уходят в slow query

> SlowTimer [4042ms] at runtime/ext_mysql: slow query: UPDATE `users` SET `last_visit` = '2015-12-22 12:30:40' WHERE `id` = '108206'
>
> SlowTimer [2513ms] at runtime/ext_mysql: slow query: UPDATE `users` SET `logins` = 'logins + 1', `last_login` = '1450803819' WHERE `id` = '426'
>
> SlowTimer [5856ms] at runtime/ext_mysql: slow query: INSERT INTO forum_online SET client='774368709', is_guest=1, last_visit=NOW() ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_visit=NOW(), is_guest=1

Задержка происходит от 1.2 до 7 сек. Индексы проставлены, таблицы не лочатся.

my.cnf

```
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
key_buffer              = 128M
key-buffer-size = 32M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = FORCE,BACKUP
max-allowed-packet = 16M
max-connect-errors = 1000000
skip-name-resolve
tmp-table-size = 32M
max-heap-table-size = 32M
query-cache-type = 0
query-cache-size = 0
max-connections = 15000
thread-cache-size = 5000
open-files-limit = 150000
table-definition-cache = 1024
table-open-cache = 50000
innodb-flush-method = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group = 2
innodb-log-file-size = 2G
innodb-file-per-table = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size = 10G
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1200
log-queries-not-using-indexes = 0
slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
table_cache            = 8192
max_heap_table_size = 256M
query_cache_limit       = 4M
query_cache_size        = 1024M
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
skip_name_resolve
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
```

На сервере ОЗУ 64 гб, Intel Xeon процы 16 ядер. mysql съедает около 3-5% CPU

Как определить причину задержки и профиксить?

Comment: может быть такое, что таблицы, используемые в запросах "заняты" другими процессами? можете проверить запросы запущенные непосредственно перед этими "медленными"?

Comment: возьмем к примеру forum_online, в таблицу идет вставка и выборка COUNT. Запрос на получение данных онлайн отрабатывает шустро, тупняки происходят именно на вставке (с рандомной периодичностью).

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: тип таблиц какой? если myisam - то на таблице блокировка скорее всего была, вот и ждали когда ее снимут. Ключи нормально проставлены? А то может там записей на несколько миллионов, а индекс отсутствует. Сам сервер как себя ведет? Может он помирал от нагрузки какой-нибудь и ему не до ваших простеньких запросов было? Можете подгадать момент, чтобы поймать такие медленные запросы и увидеть через `show process list` что еще в это время выполняется (а заодно и статус вашего медленного запроса)?

Comment: "Индексы проставлены, таблицы не лочатся" - лучше на всякий случай перепроверить это, а то можно искать проблему в другом месте, а она на виду была

Comment: тип таблиц InnoDB, записей по юзерам около 60 тыс., таблица онлайн данных пару сотен, как и писал ранее индексы проставлены. Проблема живет очень давно, аптайм сервера 3:05:00 up 117 days, 23:46,  1 user,  load average: 2.14, 2.04, 1.36

Comment: С временем переключения журналов innodb не коррелирует ? Я бы еще помониторил дисковую подсистему. может что то большое в это время пишется и файловая система решает выполнить sync. Надеюсь last_visit ни в какой индекс не включен, а то индексы запись тормозят

Comment: заметил еще пару падений мускула сегодня с ошибкой
 mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 110
возможно есть в этом связь

Comment: насчет дисковой подсистемы есть некоторые странности... например если сессии php работают стандартно с файловой системой, то при чтении данных сессии периодически отваливается с ошибкой permission denied (тоже не получается установить в чем связь, падает рандомно), переключился на redis, проблема сессий решилась, но по какой причине вылазили permission denied вопрос открытым остался. (вылетало на существующих сессиях и при последующих запросах все ок). возможно проблема на более низком уровне